# Making a character walk instead topples/flys away

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My character (I tried a bunch of types even cubes, but none seem to work) always topple or fly away, I have no idea what part of this code is wrong.

I tried changing the character, the physics, and restrictions (even restrict y-axis movement (both y-axis) and the character still flys away).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class walk : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string MoveInputAxis = "Vertical";
    private string TurnInputAxis = "Horizontal";

    // rotation that occurs in angles per second holding down input
    public float rotationRate = 360;

    // units moved per second holding down move input
    public float moveRate = 10;

    private Rigidbody rb;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        float moveAxis = Input.GetAxis(MoveInputAxis);
        float turnAxis = Input.GetAxis(TurnInputAxis);

        ApplyInput(moveAxis, turnAxis);
    }

    private void ApplyInput(float moveInput, float turnInput)
    {
        Move(moveInput);
        Turn(turnInput);
    }

    private void Move(float input)
    {
        // Make sure to set drag high so the sliding effect is very minimal 
        // (5 drag is acceptable for now)

        // mention this trash function automatically converts to local space

        rb.AddForce(transform.forward * input * moveRate, ForceMode.Force);
    }

    private void Turn(float input)
    {
        transform.Rotate(0, input * rotationRate * Time.deltaTime, 0);
    }
}
```

I expected it to turn with A and D and move with W and S, instead, it topples over and/or flys away.

Comment: Have you used an animator to decide on speed which varies it between walk/fly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable gravity (or freeze Y position), freeze rotation on all axes except Y (or whichever is your up axis), and ensure the collider is not spawning *already in a collision* with the ground (may be clipping when it spawns, causing it to shoot itself away).

Failing this, you could make the rigidbody kinematic, leaving gravity and collisions enabled, and use `transform.Translate()` to move your character isntead of `rigidbody.AddForce()`

Comment: Both of these solutions depend a lot on your requirements and intended mechanics, which are not clear.